# Official definition of CSCI (Computer Software Configuration Item)

Tags: configuration-management

I'm looking for the most official definition of CSCI / Configuration Item - not just what it is but what we have to deliver / can expect when a contract defines subsystems which shall be developed **as** configuration items.

I spend some time with my famous search tool and found a lot of explanations for CSCI (wikipedia, acronym directories, ...) but I haven't found a standard or a pointer to a standard (like ISO-xxx) yet which tells (1) what it is and (2) what has to be done from a QM/CM point of view.

I just ask, because a contractors QM representative stated during an acceptance test, that CI only requires to not forget the CI in the configuration plan and to assign a serial number ... I expected to see some SRS, SDD, ICD, SVD, SIP, ... documents and acceptance test documentation for those subsystems...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As far as I can tell, CSCI was defined in the same logic as HWCI (Hardware Configuration Item) in DOD-STD-2167A which simply defined CSCI as a configuration item.

More clear definition is in [MIL-STD-498](http://www.abelia.com/498pdf/roadmap.pdf) which superseded DOD-STD-2167A:

> CSCI - An aggregation of software that satisfies an end use function and is designated for separate configuration management by the acquirer. CSCIs are selected based on tradeoffs among software function, size, host or target computers, developer, support concept, plans for reuse, criticality, interface considerations, need to be separately documented and controlled, and other factors.

I think it would make sense when you map CSCI to a deliverable application.
A CSCI will require basically one set of SRS and SDD.
A System may comprise one or more CSCIs so other deliverable documents such as ICD and Test documents may exist for the system.

Comment: Can some add definitions for SRS, SDD, and ICD?

Answer (score 1):

Another definition can be found in [MIL-STD-881F](https://quicksearch.dla.mil/qsDocDetails.aspx?ident_number=36026):

> B.4.2.3.1 Computer Software Configuration Item (CSCI) ... An aggregation of software or any of its discrete portions that satisfies an end use function and has been designated by the Government or contractor, if the Government did not specify, for configuration management. CSCIs are the major software products of a system acquisition, which are developed in accordance with standard DoD or commercial practices and processes.

This might be preferable as the standard hasn't been cancelled.